# Convert code from c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

I am using the below code in c# page. It's working fine. I am new for vb.net. I convert the same using online converter but i got error i can't understood that error. Please help me to do the same.

```
string StrInputParam = "TYPE:5#MOBILE:" + Mobile + "#PASS:" + Password + "";
string StrSPName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SP_RED_USER_DETAILS"];
string[] ArrayVal = StrInputParam.Split('#');
    
StrSPName = Regex.Replace(StrSPName, @"\[(.+?)\]", m =>
{
    string StrParamName = m.Groups[1].Value;
    string StrParamValue = ArrayVal.Select(s => s.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2))
                                .Where(p => p.Length == 2)
                                .Where(p => p[0] == StrParamName)
                                .Select(p => p[1])
                                .FirstOrDefault();
    return StrParamValue ?? "0"; // "0" instead of m.Value
});
```

**Error**:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Replace' can be called with these arguments:
>
> 'Public Function Replace(input As String, evaluator As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator, count As Integer) As String': Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator'.
>
> 'Public Function Replace(input As String, evaluator As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator, count As Integer) As String': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'Integer' because 'Integer' is not a delegate type.......

Comment: Gee, if only there was a way that we could know what the VB output was and what the error was.  Oh well, I guess it will always be a mystery.

Comment: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Replace' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Function Replace(input As String, evaluator As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator, count As Integer) As String': Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator'.
    'Public Function Replace(input As String, evaluator As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator, count As Integer) As String': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'Integer' because 'Integer' is not a delegate type.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, I converted it for you:

```
Dim StrInputParam As String = "TYPE:5#MOBILE:" & Mobile & "#PASS:" & Password & ""
Dim StrSPName As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SP_RED_USER_DETAILS")
Dim ArrayVal() As String = StrInputParam.Split("#"c)

StrSPName = Regex.Replace(StrSPName, "\[(.+?)\]", Function(m) ' "0" instead of m.Value
      Dim StrParamName As String = m.Groups(1).Value
      Dim StrParamValue As String = ArrayVal.Select(Function(s) s.Split( { ":"c }, 2)).Where(Function(p) p.Length = 2).Where(Function(p) p(0) = StrParamName).Select(Function(p) p(1)).FirstOrDefault()
      Return If(StrParamValue, "0")
End Function)
```

Comment: Which converting application u used?

Comment: lol I converted it myself, I said that because if there was any error, you won't blame me =D

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
Dim StrInputParam As String = "TYPE:5#MOBILE:" + Mobile + "#PASS:" + Password + ""
Dim StrSPName As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SP_RED_USER_DETAILS")
Dim ArrayVal As String() = StrInputParam.Split("#"C)

StrSPName = Regex.Replace(StrSPName, "\[(.+?)\]", Function(m) 
 Dim StrParamName As String = m.Groups(1).Value
 Dim StrParamValue As String = ArrayVal.Select(Function(s) s.Split(New () {":"C}, 2))
                                       .Where(Function(p) p.Length = 2)
                                       .Where(Function(p) p(0) = StrParamName)
                                       .Select(Function(p) (1))
                                       .FirstOrDefault()
 Return If(StrParamValue, "0")   
End Function)
```

Or try this code

```
Dim StrInputParam As String =  "TYPE:5#MOBILE:" + Mobile + "#PASS:" + Password + "" 
Dim StrSPName As String =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SP_RED_USER_DETAILS") 
Dim ArrayVal() As String =  StrInputParam.Split("#"c) 

StrSPName = Regex.Replace(StrSPName, "\[(.+?)\]", m =>
{
    Dim StrParamName As String =  m.Groups(1).Value 
    Dim StrParamValue As String =  ArrayVal.Select(s  = > s.Split(New()
    {
         ":"c 
    }
, 2))
                                .Where(p => p.Length = 2)
                                .Where(p => p(0) = StrParamName)
                                .Select(p => p(1))
                                .FirstOrDefault()
    Return StrParamValue ?? "0"
}
)
```

Comment: The lambda function needs to return an _integer_, not a string (`"0"`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code :-

```
Dim StrInputParam As String = "TYPE:5#MOBILE:" & Mobile & "#PASS:" & Password & ""
Dim StrSPName As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SP_RED_USER_DETAILS")
Dim ArrayVal As String() = StrInputParam.Split("#"C)

StrSPName = Regex.Replace(StrSPName, "\[(.+?)\]", Function(m) 
Dim StrParamName As String = m.Groups(1).Value
Dim StrParamValue As String = ArrayVal.[Select](Function(s) s.Split(New () {":"C}, 2)).Where(Function(p) p.Length = 2).Where(Function(p) p(0) = StrParamName).[Select](Function(p) p(1)).FirstOrDefault()
    ' "0" instead of m.Value
Return If(StrParamValue, "0")

End Function)
```